# Add new .cs file in C# website running in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, proxy

I have a C# website running in IIS. I have few .cs files under the directory App_code. I am able to refer them in all *.aspx.cs and *.ascx.cs files. I do not have Visual studio and I need to make my changes manually.

I now need to consume a web service in .aspx.cs file. I generated a proxy class using wsdl.exe and placed it under App_code directory. But I am not able to refer to the file in my aspx.cs file. I get the error

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestSearchProxy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The proxy doesnt have any namespace defined and I am assuming that it is the default namespace. I haven't added any "using ***" in the aspx.cs fiile.

Can someone help me on how to resolve this issue?

Another approach I tried is :

I generated a dll from the proxy file using csc command and placed the dll under bin directory. I am still unable to access the proxy class.

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio (Express)?

Comment: I am working on an existing project and sln file is not compatible with the newer versions of Visual Studio express. I am new to C# and .net. Can you help me make these changes without Visual studio.

Comment: Do you have a version of MSBuild?  You could try to build the .proj file directy using: `msbuild /t:Build <name>.csproj`

Comment: I get the following error when I run MSBuild                Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 2.0.50727.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5466]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2005. All rights reserved.

.\XXXXXX.sln(2): Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

about the first attempt:

- Check the namespace of the TestSearchProxy and use it explicitly: NameSpace.TestSearchProxy
- If that doesn't work try removing the namespace from the Generated proxy code.
- Try wiping the asp.net temp directory, this will make it recompile the app_code directory from scratch. (which is usually the first thing you try since the IIS hot deploy mechanism is a bit flaky)

  1. stop the IIS service
  2. DEL /S "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files*.*"
- check for compilation errors in the proxy code, especially if the wsdl.exe you used might be from a newer framework version than the IIS/.net framework deployed in the target platform.

About the second attempt, (putting the dll in the bin directory):

- You will need to add a reference to it, you can do that from the web.config file in the root directory of your aspx website:

  <assemblies>

  <add assembly="AssemblyName , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789ABCD1"/>

  </assemblies>

  Or just by adding it to the GAC (gacutil -i dllname.dll).
- You should also check that that the dll was compiled with the correct version of .net, and in the correct architecture (x86/x64) to avoid conflicts since this might be an old system (No 4.0 clr/ 32bit only).